# Ignore files when force:source:convert

Tags: salesforcedx

My scratch orgs have this feature:

```
"features": ["DebugApex"],
```

So I create a `PermissionSet` enable this feature on the scratch org. But when running `sfdx force:source:convert --outputdir mdapi_output --packagename packageName` the permission set is included and is causing failure when pushing on an org for packaging (`sfdx force:mdapi:deploy --deploydir mdapi_output -u XXX`).

Is there a way to exclude it from packaging ? `forceignore` file excludes it from pull/push on scratch and it is not the goal.

Answer (score 1):

Create a directory structure like `donotconvert/main/default/permissionsets/` and move your debug apex permset under there. Add the `donotconvert` directory to the list of `packageDirectories` in `sfdx-project.json`. Now when you run `force:source:convert` specify the directory structure to convert using the `-r` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same sort of problem and didn't find a mechanism in SFDX for this sort of filtering.

We are using [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) as well as SFDX and that has good filtering mechanisms (and we also have files split into separate trees so need to merge those trees) so we are first copying to a new tree of files where the files we don't want are excluded and then running the convert:

```
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="./mdapi-source/staged"/>
    <delete dir="./mdapi-source/cvux"/>
</target>

<target name="convert" depends="clean">
    <copy todir="./mdapi-source/staged">
        <fileset dir="./sfdx-source/int/test"/>
        <fileset dir="./sfdx-source/int/main"/>
        <fileset dir="./sfdx-source/wiz/test">
           <exclude name="**/aura/**"/>
           <exclude name="**/staticresources/**"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="./sfdx-source/wiz/main"/>
    </copy>
    <exec dir="." executable="sfdx" osfamily="unix" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="force:source:convert"/>
        <arg value="--rootdir" />
        <arg value="./mdapi-source/staged" />
        <arg value="--outputdir" />
        <arg value="./mdapi-source/cvux" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

There might be something that helps in the [sfdx-isv/sfdx-falcon-template](https://github.com/sfdx-isv/sfdx-falcon-template) project that:

> This template can be used as a starting point for any Salesforce DX
>   project, but has been specialized for building managed packages. Each
>   directory in this repository contains a README file describing its
>   purpose, what type of files it should contain, and additional
>   setup/configuration details (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Use `.forceignore`. As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm):

> When syncing metadata between your local file system and a scratch org, you often have source files you want to exclude. Similarly, you often want to **exclude certain files when converting source** to Salesforce DX project format. In both cases, you can exclude individual files or all files in a specific directory with a .forceignore file. *(Emphasis added.)*

Comment: When push to `scratch` as well so not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

My read of the documentation is that the .forceignore file mentioned by others is only when you're pushing and pulling to the scratch org or converting from mdapi *TO* DX, not the other way around.

For our team where we just ran into this, I'm writing a bash script (but it could be written in anything) that will copy the DX force-app code tree to something like mdapimidway, prune out the files we don't want to convert and deploy and then call the convert command with the midway tree as the source to convert

```
sfdx force:source:convert -r mdapimidway/ -d mdapioutput/
```

The real power of DX isn't that it has functional parity with other tools, it's that you can throw it into the middle of your own scripts to take care of all the things they didn't think of.